# How to do a "null-table" select in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

In other words how do you do something simple like this:

```
select 1
```

Or more specifically in the particular problem I'm dealing with, something like this:

```
SELECT (case when exists (<subquery>) then 1 else 0 end) AS result
```

So in short is there a way in NHibernate to do a select without having it generate the "FROM table" clause?

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this problem wrong.

Execute the subquery you are after using a count projection then do the if else logic in code.

Comment: Thanks for responding, derek.  I wondered how quickly somebody would give me that answer :).  Using count is actually the way I'm doing it now; I just thought a simple EXISTS would be a more efficient operation since no summing is involved. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm I guess it would be more efficient, but there is no way of doing this with NHibernate short of executing the raw sql against the server. Probably not worth the performance/maintenance cost though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn that `<subquery>` into a `select top 1 id from table` style query. Then check for a non-null result. Any NH query will always start `from table`.